# MySQL INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES not adding to file size

Tags: mysql, mysql-5.7, disk-space

I have a file for a table which has grown very large. I expected to have a large amount of unallocated space needing to be optimized, but when checking INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, there is little data_free (4 MiB, 0.4 %) and the numbers do not sum to the size of the file:

```
$ sudo ls -lh /var/lib/mysql/data/modnar.ibd
-rw-r----- 1 mysql mysql 7.0G Aug 23 09:52 /var/lib/mysql/data/modnar.ibd

mysql> select table_name, engine, data_length, max_data_length, index_length, data_free from information_schema.tables where table_name = "modnar"; 
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+
| table_name | engine | data_length | max_data_length | index_length | data_free |
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+
| modnar     | InnoDB |  1172307968 |               0 |            0 |   4194304 |
+------------+--------+-------------+-----------------+--------------+-----------+
```

The file is 7 GiB but adding the numbers from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES, (1172307968+4194304)/1024/1024/1024 is only 1.1 GiB.

Why is the file so large, 7 times the amount of data in the table?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [MySQL: My table size using a query does not match the IBD's file size on disk](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264278/mysql-my-table-size-using-a-query-does-not-match-the-ibds-file-size-on-disk)

Comment: No that link does not answer my question, but my table did not have fragmentation but still looked 1/7th of the file size. A lot of blogs and SO answers keep referring to INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES when as per the percona article information in that table is often stale.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES is rarely updated and can be off by a large factor. Extensive details from percona: https://www.percona.com/blog/2016/01/26/finding_mysql_table_size_on_disk/

INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES is always up to date, indeed:

```
mysql> select * from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES where name = 'data/modnar';
+-------+-------------+------+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+----------------+
| SPACE | NAME        | FLAG | FILE_FORMAT | ROW_FORMAT | PAGE_SIZE | ZIP_PAGE_SIZE | SPACE_TYPE | FS_BLOCK_SIZE | FILE_SIZE  | ALLOCATED_SIZE |
+-------+-------------+------+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+----------------+
|    54 | data/modnar |   33 | Barracuda   | Dynamic    |     16384 |             0 | Single     |          4096 | 7470055424 |     7470059520 |
+-------+-------------+------+-------------+------------+-----------+---------------+------------+---------------+------------+----------------+
```

Running OPTIMIZE on the modnar table did update INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES for which the numbers now add up to 6.25 GiB.

A query to find which table use large amount of unallocated space from up to date data:

```
select name, unallocated_KB, round(unallocated_KB/(fs_block_size/1024)) unallocated_blocks, unallocated_KB/(file_size/1024) unallocated_percent from (
  select name, fs_block_size, file_size, (ALLOCATED_SIZE - FILE_SIZE)/1024 unallocated_KB
  from INFORMATION_SCHEMA.INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES
  where name not like 'mysql/%' and name not like 'sys/%'
  order by unallocated_KB
  ) as tables;
```

Comment: 6.25 GB is still not accurate but way closer. From the .ibd and INFORMATION_SCHEMA, the real fragmentation is 0.75GB (7 - 6.25). See my old posts  https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/110996/how-to-monitor-mysql-percentage-disk-utilization/110997#110997 and https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/264278/mysql-my-table-size-using-a-query-does-not-match-the-ibds-file-size-on-disk/264288#264288

Comment: If data_length + index_length is 1.1 GB, then fragmentation is really 5.9 GB. This might have occurred after a mass DELETE or some large UPDATEs. You should run `pt-online-schema-change ... --alter "ENGINE=InnoDB"` and shrink that table.

Comment: That table is added on only, no updates, no deletion. It turned out the INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES was not being updated as explained in the percona article. Also note that after I ran optimize, the data_length reflected the real value, because optimize forces an update on INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES.